# Multiple JoinColumns pointing to the same non-pk columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, joincolumn

Imagine the following entities

```
EntityA (the combination of attr1, attr2 is unique){
    - pk
    ...
    - attr1
    - attr2
    ...
    other unique attributes
}
 EntityB (the combination of attr1, attr2 is unique) {
    - pk
    ...
    - attr1
    - attr2
    ...
    other unique attributes
}
 EntityC (the combination of attr1, attr2 is not unique){
    - pk
    ...
    - attr1
    - attr2
    ...
    other unique attributes
}
```

**attr1** and **attr2** fields are the same type on all 3 entities.
On Entity1 I would like to create a JoinColumns based join for both Entity1 and Entity2 as follows:

```
EntityA (the combination of attr1, attr2 is unique){
    - pk
    ...
    - attr1
    - attr2
    ...
    other unique attributes
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)        
    @JoinColumns(
            value = {
                    @JoinColumn(
                            name = "attr1", referencedColumnName = "attr1",
                            updatable = false, insertable = false),
                    @JoinColumn(
                            name = "attr2", referencedColumnName = "attr2",
                            updatable = false, insertable = false)
            })
    EntityB entityB;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(
            value = {
                    @JoinColumn(
                            name = "attr1", referencedColumnName = "attr1",
                            updatable = false, insertable = false),
                    @JoinColumn(
                            name = "attr2", referencedColumnName = "attr2",
                            updatable = false, insertable = false)
            })
    List<EntityC> entityCList;
}
```

With the definition above, I get the following error:

> Referenced column 'attr2' mapped by target property 'entityB' occurs out of order in the list of '@JoinColumn's

If I remove the definition of either entityB or entityB, the remaining one works properly.
(Note: my goal with the non-bidirectional relationship is only to be able to fetch the necessary related objects, nothing more, that is why I am trying to define it this way instead of a separate query, so I can directly get the data via the getters.)

Comment: Why nor create a EntityD with the attr1 and attr2, and then you just have a primary in the 3 entities.

Comment: @Scoby attr1 and attr2 are "just" simple primitive attributes. They do not count as individual objects and for some cases their combination does not make the owner object unique (eg. EntityC).